# MySql create a user for an ip

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I want to connect to my sql server only from a open vpn ip, and in heidisql it dose not work, I have open vpn active and I recive that is acces denied from my real ip and vpn is active. Thanks.

```
CREATE USER '[MYUSER]'@'%[MYVPNIP] IDENTIFIED BY '[MYPASSWORD]'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see [ask] to improve your question. What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Your create statement seems to be wrong. You have an extra % where it is not needed:

`CREATE USER '[MYUSER]'@'[MYVPNIP]' IDENTIFIED BY '[MYPASSWORD]'`

Although, since you're wanting to connect through your VPN, you have to make sure that your OS is configured to fully-tunnel network traffic through the VPN. On a Mac, this is a simple matter of editing the VPN connection in the Network Preferences, clicking the advanced tab, and checking the box labeled "Send all traffic over VPN connection." However I don't know about other OSes ;)